# javascript in php: Document.forms not function

Tags: javascript, php

In php:

```
if (isset($close_subject)) {
    $sql_close = "delete from content_tree where user_id='$id' and subject_id='$close_subject'";
    $result_close = mysql_query($sql_close);
}

function xxx()
{
<a href="#"  onClick="closeSubject('<? echo $set_subject[subject_id] ?>')"><img border="0" align="absmiddle" src="../../pic/tree/open.png"></a>
}
```

In HTML:

```
xxx();
<script type="text/javascript">
function closeSubject(id) 
{
    document.close_subject_form.close_subject.value = id;
    document.close_subject_form.submit();
}
</script>


<form name="close_subject_form" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="close_subject" name="close_subject">
</form>
```

Hi, I have some codes like above. I wan to delete the record in database. But it is not function >.< anyone can help?

Comment: Can you check what your call get converted to?? I mean, try to check once your page loads if your PHP gets evaluated correctly, your <a> tag event should look like onClick="closeSubject('id')" Can you confirm it is correct?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You say 'I wan to close the expanded content tree', but with this javascript function you will submit your form. So where is the 'close the expanded content' part?

Comment: Sorry, I hv edit my question~ Actually is I want to delete the record in database~

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: But the php version i use is only 5.3.6, and i can manage the database without document.form >.< but this case is i need to use document.form >.<

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteshit($id,$close_subject){
mysql_query("delete from content_tree where user_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."' and    subject_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($close_subject)."'");
return mysql_affected_rows();
}
```

also, if, contrary to best guess, you have any idea what you're doing,  check out this shit http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers